# Android Intent chooser - wrong propositions

Tags: android, android-intent, gallery, filechooser

I want to open any file in my app using intent chooser - unfortunately, propositions from chooser are... weird. After choosing `png` file it displays only one option - Drive PDF Viewer. But when I try to open the same file using default files explorer it correctly recommends using Galery or Photos.

```
String mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext.toLowerCase());
Log.i(TAG, mime); // <------------ image/png
Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setType(mime);
intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));  // <----- png file
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an application to open with:");
chooser.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(chooser);
```

Whats wrong here?

Comment: If you change it to: intent.setType("image/*"); it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this with `setDataAndType`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "image/*");
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an application to open with:");
context.startActivity(chooser);
```

Please see the Javadoc of the method setType(String type) in the class Intent:
...
**This method automatically clears any data that was previously set (for example by setData(Uri)).**
...

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
String[] mimetypes = {"image/*"};
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
```

This may helps you

Comment: This opens activity with message: `All apps associated with this action have been turned off, blocked, or are not installed`... but I'm pretty sure that GALERY app is installed (it works in default file explorer)

Answer (score 0):

try addind this insted mime

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Image"),REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_IMAGE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same message popping up for me too when i used the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.coordinator_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gotoA);
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            intent.putExtra("show 1",true);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gotoB);
    textView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            intent.putExtra("show 2",true);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

so i brought the intent contructor to where i am using that intent instance.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Intent intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.coordinator_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gotoA);
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("show 1",true);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gotoB);
    textView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("show 2",true);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

for me this solved the issue.